# Get listItems with graph filtered by lastUpdateDate and parentListName

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to use Graph API to retrieve the list of all sharepoint list items for which :

1. LastModifiedDate > 2022-01-01
2. ParentListName = 'MyParentList'

I actually make this call :
POST : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

Body :

```
{
    "requests": [{
        "entityTypes": [
            "listItem"
        ],
        "query": {
            "queryString": "(LastModifiedTime > 2022-01-01)"
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 1000,
"expand":"fields"
    }]
}
```

It seems to work to select only listItems updated after the required date, but at this stage, I'm not able to select only listItems where parentListName = 'MyListName'.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to modify query string to:

```
{
    ...
    "query": {
        "queryString": "(LastModifiedTime > 2022-01-01 AND listId:<list-guid>)"
    }
    ...
}
```